# What's the reason/primary benefit of jQuery 1.5's jqXHR?

Tags: jquery, jqxhr

I'm curious, what are the intentions of the jqXHR wrapper? Is there something about it that improves development?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It implements XHR-like functionality for non-XHR transports (think JSONP, etc.) Also, it allows you do to Promises. The best place to read up on this is right in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: Ya, I've read that page... was more or less looking at a benefit analysis. It essentially looks like the "Promises" interface is a way to object orient the ajax response?

Comment: @Chad - Like many other things jQuery, it is primarily to abstract away what otherwise requires a lot of browser-specific code.

Comment: @Christian, thanks! That is a very good thing. I've since begun using it, and I'm really digging it.

Comment: There is an opinion that [jQuery Promises are broken](http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/). Whether you agree or not, it's worth reading and understanding the difference.